# custom last child menu item html in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

in my menu item need to change last child html can help me to change it. thanks

my html:

```
    <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page icon-chevron-right menu-item-21"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
    </ul>
```

like this:

```
    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page icon-chevron-right menu-item-21"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/sample-page/">Sample Page<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Abbas, if you want to just add icon then you may add it directly to admin, or do you need the code solution for it?

Comment: need add icon to sub menu. think code is better way

Comment: Is it always to the last one? Or is it to a specific menu item (ie. `menu-item-21`)?  What you'd want to do is target the last child of the sub-menu, then append your icon to the `<a href="">`.
However, as you already have the `icon-chevron-right` in the `<li>` class, why not just add the icon using after in CSS?  `.sub-menu li.icon-chevron-right a:after{ content:'the icon code/image'; }` and then it's just a matter of working through the CSS to get it looking exactly as you want it to.

Comment: i need just last sub menu give icon to show in menu